# Spring Roo cant create unit tests

Tags: spring-roo

i have a workspace that has a master project that has the parent pom.xml file it in, then 38 other projects that share that parent pom.

in one of my child projects, i am trying to create unit tests on a spring service class i created and its not working. when i do

```
test integration --entity foo.bar
```

i get

```
Command 'test integration --entity foo.bar' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)
```

which gives me just slightly less information than a typical Microsoft error message. why isn't this working?

Answer (score 0):

This means that something that 'test integration' depends on is missing from the project.

I had the same problem when trying to run 'entity mongo'...  basically, I had removed dependencies from my pom.xml that roo needed in order to support database persistence.  So to fix mine, I ran 'mongo setup' again, to see what it added to my project, and I was able to run the entity and repository commands again.

My guess is that if you go through the same process (possibly with jpa instead of mongo, depending on what you are using) you will see what was missing, and be able to run the 'test integration' command again.

In my case, I had removed the dependencies on hibernate-validation and cloudfoundry because I wasn't using either of them, but when I put them back in, I was able to run the roo persistence commands again.